# Angular ui-grid tooltip not displaying

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to apply a simple filter on ui-grid cells and add a tooltip to them but it's not working.
The filter is working correctly but not the tooltip. it's only displayed when I remove the  filter.
`cellFilter: 'number: 2', cellTooltip: 'Custom tooltip - maybe some help text'`
here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SvjMbZDwfrnrOipap0B0?p=preview) with the example I'm talking about.
any help is really apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this issue introducing custom filter - formatNumber to format the number **`cellFilter: 'formatNumber:2'`** with tooltip -

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name'
    }, {
      field: 'amount',
      name: 'Number',
      cellFilter: 'formatNumber:2',
      cellTooltip: 'Custom tooltip - maybe some help text'

    }, {
      field: 'amount',
      name: 'Currency',
      cellFilter: 'formatNumber:2',
      cellTooltip: 'Custom tooltip - maybe some help text'
    }, ]
  };

  $http.get('data.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
}]);

app.filter('formatNumber', function() {
  return function(input, decimalPlaces) {
    if (isNaN(input))
      return input;
    else {
      return input.toFixed(decimalPlaces);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: thank you for your solution that fixes my issue, I just updated ` input.toFixed(decimalPlaces);` with ` Number(input).toFixed(decimalPlaces);` however do you have any idea how can I apply a cell template of tooltip for this example. like `cellTemplate: '<div class="grid-tooltip" uib-tooltip="The applied margin for extra revenues is X %" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true"><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" >{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}</div></div>'` and keep the filter working? Thank you in advance

Comment: Create function on tooltip e.g.  cellTooltip: function(row, col) {
          return 'Name: ' + row.entity.name + ' Company: ' + row.entity.company;
        }

Comment: I mean applying something like this `cellTemplate: '<div class="grid-tooltip" tooltip="{{ row.entity.state }}" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true"><div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{ COL_FIELD }}</div></div>'` that will allow me to use uib-tooltip for the tooltip

Comment: here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0JR2Uxx2TddcS7KYB4kX?p=preview)